# Removing MS Word XML tags that split text

Tags: python, regex, xml, ms-word

I am trying to edit text using python regex that originates from an MS Word document that has been created by someone else. The document has specific formatting and equations that need to be preserved. I save the .docx file as a .xml and edit with python. Unfortunately, Word adds XML tags that split the words and messes with my regular expressions. Example(this is the format that Word outputs):

`awe</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00106B67"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/><w:sz w:val="21"/><w:szCs w:val="21"/></w:rPr><w:t>some`

I have attempted to remove the tags with regular expressions and have had little success. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The solution does not have to incorporate Python or regex

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a regex, but try this on for size:

```
s = """awe</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00106B67"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/><w:sz w:val="21"/><w:szCs w:val="21"/></w:rPr><w:t>some"""

answer = []
depth = 0
for char in s:
    if char == "<": depth += 1
    elif char == ">": depth -= 1

    if depth: continue
    if char == ">": continue

    answer.append(char)

print(''.join(answer))
```